# ideas for a distributed cache proxy server

Tags: c++, c, distributed-caching

I am implementing, a distributed cache proxy server.I have an idea of the HTTP and related stuff, so i am rather concentrating on the sub part "Distributed data storage".

From some search on web i found that this could be done using Distributed Hash Tables(DHT).
I was wondering if there exists some kind of library for this preferably in C/C++.

Any better suggestions for the same will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Kademlia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia)?  There's [KadC](http://kadc.sourceforge.net/) (C) and [maidsafe-dht](http://code.google.com/p/maidsafe-dht/) (C++) for it.